# php login form not working correctly

Tags: php, database, mysqli, database-connection

I'm trying to create a simple login functionality but it's not working, and I'm relatively new to mysqli so please bear with me.  I just want to check if the email address and password are correct and if they are then log the user in.  Thanks in advance.

Here is my login code that checks the credentials:

**UPDATED CODE** - I added the report all and I'm now getting internal server error

```
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);


session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {

$e = trim($_REQUEST['email']);
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($e);
$p = trim($_REQUEST['password']);
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($p);

/*
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email, password, user_id" .
                                             " FROM users" .
                                             " WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
echo 'Total results: ' . $result->num_rows;

}
*/

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email, password, user_id FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($email, $password);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

   if ($stmt->num_rows==1) {
   $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc(MYSQLI_NUM);
   $user_id = $row['user_id'];
   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
   $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
   header("Location: home.php");

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    printf("Error message: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
/*
if ($result->num_rows==1) {
$row = $result->fetch_assoc(MYSQLI_NUM);
   $user_id = $row['user_id'];

if ($query_group = $mysqli->query("SELECT *" .
                                                        " FROM user_groups" .
                                                        " WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'")) {
   //No more setcookie
   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
   $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
} else {
echo 'Did not work';
}
}
*/

    /* free result set */
    // $result->close();
}
}

?>
```

And here is connect.php to connect to the database:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("data", "username", "password", "db");

if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $mysqli->connect_error . ']');
}

?>
```

Comment: When I hit submit on my form it just gives me a blank page with the url stuck on login.php

Comment: use die(mysqli_error($connection)); and try to print $row.

Comment: While developing, you should configure PHP to display errors on the webpage or at least to a log file.  You should use those error messages to debug.  Note also that you don't provide any output or result if login is denied, so it's possible the issue isn't a PHP error but a bad login.

Comment: right after you require add `die("error : " . mysqli_error($mysqli));`. if everything good move the code later in your code. if that also works move the code later. keep doing this until you get an error or nothing shows up.

Comment: When I put `die("error : " . mysqli_error($mysqli));` after `require 'connect.php';` i still get an internal server error

Comment: Show your connect.php

Answer (score 0):

did you try to remove one of the brackets in the end of ypur code. I guess you have to remove one of them.

Comment: That didn't do anything

Comment: I have this `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);` is that what you're talking about?

Comment: sorry for being not so clear. no, i mean did you set that in your php.ini file, because you didn't mention any specific error. if you set display error relevant error would be displayed.

Comment: No I didn't, I only have it in my login.php file.  I do have the code for my connect.php file above now